# Take integral of $\int 1/x \,dz$ where $z=x+y$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate

$$\int \frac{1}{x} \,dz$$

where the measure is the total differential of $z=x+y$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ are variables. I wonder if the result should simply be:

$$\int \frac{1}{x}\, dz = \int \frac{1}{x} \,dx+\int \frac{1}{x} \,dy = C_1+\log(x)+\frac{y}{x}$$

This seems too easy to be true. How should I compute this integral properly?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $x$ and $y$ are independent variables the $1$-form
$$\omega:={1\over x}(dx+dy)$$
is *not* exact, since ${\rm curl}\left({1\over x},{1\over x}\right)=-{1\over x^2}\not\equiv0$. This means that there is *no* function $f:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ defined in some domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ such that $\omega=df$, which then could serve as a kind of "indefinite integral" in your example.

What makes sense however are line integrals along curves
$$\gamma:\quad [a,b]\to\Omega,\qquad t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)\ .$$
For such a curve the integral
$$\int_\gamma\omega=\int_\gamma {1\over x}(dx+dy)=\int_a^b{1\over x(t)}\bigl(x'(t)+y'(t)\bigr)\>dt$$
is well defined, but its value depends  on the full data inherent in $\gamma$, and not only on the endpoints of $\gamma$.

Comment: Thank you! This clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$z = x + y \implies x = z - y$$
Then the integral becomes
$$\int\frac1x\mathrm dz = \int\frac1{z - y}\mathrm dz = \ln(z - y) + C$$
since $y$ is constant with respect to $z$.

Comment: I thought about that, but the thing is - if $y$ is constant with respect to $z$, then you could argue with the same logic that $x$ itself is constant with respect to $z$, such that $\int \frac{1}{x}dz=\frac{z}{x}=1+\frac{y}{x}$. Which is yet another solution that is different from mine and yours above...

Comment: @Kagaratsch: I don't think $x$ is constant with respect to $z$, since $x$ is a *function* of $z$. You could have also written $x(z) = z - y$.

Comment: Exactly, and that is also true for $y$. Namely: $y(z)=z-x$. Therefore, either $x$ AND $y$ are constant in $z$, or both are functions of $z$ on the same grounds. (Clearly, only the second statement can be correct.)

Comment: @Kagaratsch: I'm not fully convinced, but this is interesting, so I hope someone with more expertise will answer your question!

Comment: @Kagaratsch: After the substitution $y$ cannot be anything but a constant with respect to $z$. I'm definitely not convinced by your argument. Also, if you try to differentiate the result with respect to $z$ you get the initial integral. This, however, is true for you solution as well. I suspect that they are in fact equivalent. $y/x$ is a constant so you could write $C_1 + y/x = C_2$ and the solutions would be equivalent.

Comment: Except, if you substitute $log(x)\rightarrow log(z-y)$ in my solution, you also would have to take $y/x\rightarrow y/(z-y)$, because, why think of $x$ as a function in one term and as a constant in another? Also, my example from the comments above would not fit anyhow, yet is based on the same logic.

Comment: @Kagaratsch: Asking WolframAlpha yields these results: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fx+dz+where+z+%3D+x+%2B+y and http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fx+dz+where+x+%3D+z+-+y I'm not sure of how one should interpret them.